# Publish website to IIS, server locks dll files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, dll, publish

I've been struggling with this problem for about a week. I'm trying to publish my MVC website to my IIS server using FTP. The only problem is that when I transfer the files, MVC always locks up some DLL files (System.Web.MVC etc.) and it releases them 10 minutes later.

This problem prevents my site to be consistently up and gives a very ugly error message.

When trying to delete the bin folder I get access denied, when trying to rename the bin folder I get access denied and when trying to delete the specific file I also get access denied.

Also, I can't run any programs that shut down the processes since it's not my server and I do not have access to the actual machine.

How can I publish my site smoothly without having these problems?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using [web deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)?

Comment: I simply don't know how to work with it using my server. How can I use it in my server and what information I need to provide to the web deploy wizard?

Comment: IIS chaches some DLL files that are actually web services. If they are called once, the are cached and loaded so they become write protected. Not sure if this helps. But if you need to change only static files that are not web services why are you not using an FTP Client instead?

Comment: I am using FTP client. How can I stop this cache when I want to publish.

Comment: I guess thats something on the server sided configuration but you could probably remove those DLL files from your project to avoid publishing it if not required.

Comment: Can you show us the web.config file?

Comment: What happens if you recycle the application pool just before you publish?

Comment: How can i recycle the application pool?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. For now I recycle the application pool before Publishing and that will release all locks on dll files.

I hope to find a better solution soon.

Comment: in the commends someone also suggest to `recycle` the `application pool` just before publishing. But the user mentioned that he doesn't know it works so please extend your answer with dome steps.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. The steps I take are as follows:

1. Open IIS manager
2. Expand the server name
3. Click on Application Pools
4. Select the application pool where your current website is running within.
5. In the right menu, click on Recycle. That will release a lock on one of the dll files that is recreated when you publish your project again.
6. Publish your MVC website. Now it will work.

Hope this will help.